# Event for radio button being selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there some event for a radio button being selected?

I know I can use "click" but I believe it is possible to style radio buttons in some browsers such that clicking an outter area of a radio button might not select the radio button.

What event should I use?

Comment: Hi the click would always work on all browsers.. I dont find what u mean the outer area... Do u want to activate the click event even for labels?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends when you want to be informed of the event.

If you want to know immediately, go with `click`. IE updates the state of `checked` before the handler function is called, and I *think* the other browsers do as well. You may want to double check as I only have IE to work with right now.

If you only need to know before something else happens, you can use `change`. IE will not fire the `change` event until the selected radio button loses focus. FF/chrome/others may fire the event without focus changing, but I believe IE is actually doing it right in this case.

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated.  `input` is a better goto these days.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `onchange` event, which will fire when the radio selection is changed (ie. the first time a radio button in the group is clicked or when the selection within the group is changed).

See http://jsfiddle.net/P9Z9Y/1/ for a simple example (clicking on either the label or the radio button itself will trigger an `alert` if the radio group's value changes).

Comment: Note that this will in IE only get fired when the input loses focus. Clicking a button would only keep its focus. You'd like to click/tab somewhere else thereafter to let it to lose focus and thus get the `change` event to fire.

Comment: @Balus that's not the case for radio buttons in Firefox or Chrome (onchange on a radio button fires immediately on a click that changes the radio group value, and even when clicking on an associated `<label>`, see my updated jsfiddle). I don't have a newer version of IE here to test with.

Comment: Or IE (back to version 4), NN 4.x, Safari, Opera, or even the Lotus Notes client either. For keyboard-editable fields, yes, but not for radio buttons.

Comment: Works just find on IE11 by the way (yay for five years of improvement)

Comment: (Although onclick also works just as well, at least in this situation)

Answer (score 2):

did you try using the onchange event?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how new the `input` event is, but it's generally the best bet.  Handles keyboard nav and the like.  Updates immediately.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event