# Change css based in Select option value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have in one form, one selects with one question that if determined value selected I need to display none the next question. How can I make a jquery code that detects that the user selected a determinated option in select and change the CSS of the page?

```
<select>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Show what you've got and we'll see what you need/ might improve on

Comment: This might be of some use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325864/how-to-display-an-output-depending-on-the-selected-radio-button-after-selecting

Comment: @jamesS for now, i just have the form structure, i edited the question with an example.

Comment: @Rizwan ive added a jsfiddle to my answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague, but i think this is what your after:

```
 const value = $('#selectID option[value=""]').prop("selected", true);

 if (value....") {
     // do css stuff
 }
```

Additionally you can get the value / text like so:

```
<select id="car_manufacturer">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
   const element = document.getElementById("car_manufacturer");
   const value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
   const text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
 </script>
```

You could extend on the above with a on onchange event on the select element.

```
<select id="car_manufacturer" onchange="selectManufacturer(this)">
```

**Manipulate CSS:**

JavaScript:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").css("background-color","red");
```

**Fiddle**

`onchange` example with css manipulation:

http://jsfiddle.net/9L0czmeq/

Comment: Nice, but i need to change css when select change value.

Comment: very nice @David, how can i use a class instead of body to change the css here: document.body.style.display = "none";??

Comment: jQuery - .addClass $( "#id" ).addClass( "class" ); there is also a .removeClass

Comment: JavaScript - var element = document.getElementById("div");
  element.classList.add("class");

Answer (score 2):

**So as far as I understand with your short description you need to do something based on the value selected by user in select box which we call an event onchange.I am writing a code example for you**

```
<select onchange="somefunction($(this).val())">
 <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 </select>

<script>
  function somefunction(value){
     if(value == 1){
      $("body").css("background-color","red");
     }
     if(value == 2){
       $("body").css("background-color","yellow");
     }
  }
   </script>
```

Comment: Can you please make a code with all in javascript code? withou puting "onchange="somefunction($(this).val())" in select tag.

Comment: $("#car_manufacturer").onchange(function(){ }); you can also do like this

Comment: yes it can work. add a body tag to your jsfiddle and you will see the effect

Comment: I don't use jsfiddle but on my IDE i have tested. its working fine

Comment: @Rizwan it works fine in my IDE, but when i put it on my site i got this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: somefunction is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ((index):2473)
onchange @ (index):2473

can you make this code all in the script?